# Adding more than one organisation domain on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I am using `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem in Rails. I have created account on GCP & created project under organisation `example.com`

The problem is when I created app on GCP and created omni-oauth `client-id` & `client-secret-key`, I did setting under, 'Oauth Consent Screen'

- Public - Any Google Account can grant access to the scopes required by this app.
- Internal - Only users with a Google Account in your organization can grant access to the scopes requested by this app.

I chose `internal` & now only emails having domain `example.com` can access & `example.in` cannot.
I want to do setup for .in domain also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add another domain follow these steps:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Go to APIs & Services -> Credentials.
3. Select the tab `OAuth consent screen`.
4. Under `Application domains` notice the text box with `example.com`.
5. Enter the next domain name and press `ENTER`.
6. Click Save.

Comment: Does this work? I can only see a section for `Authorised domains` - which is for application domains, not user identity domains